# stored procedure that takes Query results as parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i just created a stored procedure that take a parameter(example id) and copies columns related to that id from one table to another table.
How can i create stored procedure that takes sub query results as parameter,database is mysql..

This is my example..i want to pass query that select id from table to procedure..

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`sasi`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sasi`(IN idno int(4))

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user5(id,email,address,fullname,gender,phonenumber)
    SELECT id,email,address,fullname,gender,phonenumber FROM user1  where id != idno;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;

call sasi(4);
```

Comment: Which DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Pass the XMl param or table parameter to Sp if using Sql server 2008.

Comment: thanks for replying Romil..iam using MYSQL

Comment: thanks for your quick response @a_horse_with_no_name any suggestions..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To pass the results of a query into your stored procedure, wrap the query in brackets.
For example:

```
call sasi((select max(id) from sometable where somecondition));
```

You must make sure the query only returns one row and one column.

#### Edited:

If you want to call the procedure multiple times, once for each row, change your procedure to be a [`FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sasi(idno int(4))
RETURNS int(4)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user5(id,email,address,fullname,gender,phonenumber)
    SELECT id,email,address,fullname,gender,phonenumber FROM user1  where id != idno;
    RETURN idno;
END
```

Then call it like this:

```
select sasi(id)
from table
where ...
```

`sasi(id)` will get called for every row matching the `where` clause.

Comment: thanks for replying @Bohemian ..if i want to pass result set there..i mean 'select id from sometable1 where id in(select id from sometable2)'..it gives me some id ..i want to pass them as my parameter..

Comment: your suggestion works well @Bohemian ,but i need Procedure that takes query that return resultset

Comment: You can't do that, but you can write a stored proc to loop over result set and call your proc for every row. See [the mysql doc about cursors inside stored procs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html). The other option is to change your proc to be *function*, and do this `select sasi(id) from table where ...` and it will call it once for every row. See edited answer